# Updating Service reference in web reference .net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, asmx

We a legacy 3.5 web app which refers WCF service in their web reference. Are web reference are meant for consuming old .asmx services and service reference are mean consuming for .svc (WCF) right?

Now the WCF service endpoint got changed and how i would update this in VS 2010.

Our build target is limited to .net 3.5

Comment: Wouldn't you simply update the reference via add service reference, using the new endpoint, and then rebuild the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the endpoint is all that changed, that is the service contract stayed the same, then you should just be able to update the endpoint in your app.config file.  No recompile required.